# How to run multiple bash/sh scripts in xcode 5 during build phase?

Tags: build-process, xcode5

I have a need to run two (2) bash/sh scripts in XCode 5 during the build phase.  One creates a connection to Crashlytics, the other creates a Mainstoryboard.strings file with modifications from the original.

How do I do this?  Just run them one after the other?  (Looked in Google and SO... found nothing that addresses this question).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can run as many bash scrips as you like at any point in the build phase.

select your target, then either:

- from the menu: Editor -> Add Build Phase -> Add run script build phase.
- Click the little "+" icon in the top left of the build phases window.

you can then drag the build phases into which ever order you need.

Comment: Thank you... it's amazing what's hidden in the Menu... :D

Comment: There used to be a button down at the bottom of the "build phases" section, but that seems to have vanished with Xcode 5 for whatever reason...

Comment: The "Add" button is now at the _top_ of the phases' list. It's rendered as a "+" sign.

Comment: @GrahamPerks Thanks! I dont know how I missed it. Updated answer with this info.